# ASP.NET MVC using response.write not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, response.write

Can anyone tell how to write you own method and call it view or simply write "Hello world" in the following manner? This is what I tried to write on my

Index.cshtml:

```
<h1>
    Hello,
    <span>
        @{ HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("World!"); }
    </span>
</h1>
```

but it is not working? Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Write` is use for write string content to the responce,

If you want to bind your test to the view than you can create a model for the view and initialize from controller and pass it to the view see below example,

Here my model is type of `string`, you can create your complax model if thare are more than one property

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("index","World!");
}
```

View:

```
@model string
<h1>
    Hello,
    <span>
        @Model
    </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: I am getting this error now : 
Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'World!' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/World!.aspx
~/Views/Home/World!.ascx
~/Views/Shared/World!.aspx
~/Views/Shared/World!.ascx
~/Views/Home/World!.cshtml
~/Views/Home/World!.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/World!.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/World!.vbhtml

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this worked for me: 
Controller: ViewBag.Message = "World!";
                 return View();


View : <span>@ViewBag.Message </span>

Comment: @VVG24 but if you have more properties than you need to bind to model that would be appropriate way

Comment: yes I agree. But, I was still getting the same error (even after the correction)

Comment: @VVG24 your view name should be index.cshtml and it shuold inside controller name foler, i.e. if your controller name is HomeController than view should be in views/home folder